# How to pass value from html to server side code?

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net classic. I am trying to pass a value that is inside of a div from .aspx file to a function inside of aspx.cs. function How should would I go about doing this? I not sure if this best to approach this problem. But essentially I need to get the current page number and send it my function. [need to get page number from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnXBL.png)

```
    <ItemTemplate><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" CssClass='<%# Eval("Enabled").ToString()=="False"?"btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled":"" %>' runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' Enabled = '<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick = "Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
</span></ItemTemplate>

 <asp:LinkButton  OnClick="myfunction"  />
```

then inside of my aspx.cs file

```
protected void myfunction (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I need to get value from inside of ItemTemplate
}
```

To be more specific I need to get value `<a>`where the `class != "disabled"`

```
<div>
<span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_0" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl00$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">First</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_1" class="aspNetDisabled btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled">1</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_2" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl02$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">2</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_3" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl03$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">3</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_4" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl04$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">4</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_5" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl05$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">5</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a  id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_6" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl06$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">&gt;&gt;</a>
</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> 
    <a class="disabled" id="cpPageContent_rptPager_lnkPage_7" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpPageContent$rptPager$ctl07$lnkPage&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Last</a>
</span>
<br><br>
     </div>
```

Comment: I've removed the ASP Classic tag because you're clearly working with ASP.NET, not .asp files with VBScript in them (which is what Classic ASP is).

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar It is not asp.net core

Comment: I never said it was. There is Classic ASP, which was superseded by ASP.NET in 2002, and ASP.NET Core was released in 2016. Please see [these Classic ASP examples](https://riptutorial.com/asp-classic) to understand what Classic ASP is. You are using ASP.NET, not Classic ASP, and not ASP.NET Core. Understand?

Comment: I also suggest you read the description of the tag that you misused: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp-classic/info - You should read the descriptions of tags before you apply them to your question, so that you know they are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here looks like the ASP.NET component (`asp:LinkButton` in this case) has a click handler attached at the server side (`OnClick = "Page_Changed"`) but in the same time you seem to set the `CommandArgument`.

The latter is a strong indication that your component is inside a `GridView` or a `ListView` or yet another (possibly custom) templated component that accepts events from its children.

The following part of the answer assumes that this is your case, that indeed, you have a grid view or a list view and your component is a part of its template.

If this is so, this is your chance to consume component events at the server. Your `CommandArgument` is already there but you seem to miss the `CommandName`, which basically lets you distinguish between different child events.

Assuming then your component is a `ListView` (is it?), you'd have

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" ... OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">
        ...
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" CssClass='<%# Eval("Enabled").ToString()=="False"?"btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled":"" %>' runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandName="PageChange" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' Enabled = '<%# Eval("Enabled") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Note that I've added the `OnItemCommand` handler on the parent component and the `CommandName` on the actual child.

Then, you just handle the item command

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "PageChange":

           // this is what you are looking for
           string argument = e.CommandArgument;

           break;

    }
}
```

The `CommandName` / `CommandArgument` duo is passed in the `ListViewCommandEventArgs`, thus, at the server side you have both in the very same item command handler.

Note that other child components can possibly have other `CommandName`s and still the same handler is used at the server side, thus, the handler is a big `switch` over different command names.